# Transform array containing arrays with a single element into single depth array

Tags: php, arrays

I was wondering if there is a better solution to this: Transform an array containing arrays with a single value into an array of one less depth. I.e.

The array prints like this:

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [item_1] => 5
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [item_2] => 7
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [item_4] => 1
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [item_5] => 1
    )

)
```

and should get transformed to print like:

```
Array
(
[item_1] => 5
[item_2] => 7
[item_4] => 1
[item_5] => 1
)
```

Right now I achieve this with this code:

```
$items = array(...) // retrieved from db
$counts = array();
foreach ($items as $item) {
    foreach ($item as $key => $val) {
        $counts[$key] = $val;
    }
}
```

**Is there a better way to combine the array items of the contained arrays into a single array?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Untested, but should work:

```
$items = array(...);
$counts = array_reduce($items,"array_merge",array());
```

Comment: Works like a charm! And I will have to remember that the callback function can just as well be any other php function, that is to say, needn't be a function written myself! Ty